# CoqIDE: the reference was not found in the current environment

Tags: coqide

I just start to learn coq and I basically copied the code (?) from what the professor showed in the class but it never worked on my laptop!
I have no idea why it keep telling me that the reference y was not found in the current environment.
And there is only two sentences(?) in my coqIDE:

```
Require Export Utf8.
Notation "x->y" :=(x->y)(at level 99).
```

I've read some webpages asking similar questions but I don't think we had the same problem. If I'm wrong, sorry about that.
In addition, could you please tell me what does "Utf8" and "at level 99" suppose to mean??

I know these are stupid questions but I just don't understand.
Thank you for taking a look at it:)